# SQL Case When Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm getting ORA-00936 missing expression error in oracle sql. I couldnt find where the mistake is. Can anyone help me? thank you

```
 case when (select p.template_id from ifsapp.PURCHASE_ORDER_APPROVAL p where p.template_id='T0009' and p.order_no=po.order_no) then 'NOT QC APPROVED'
  when sp.qc_approval_db = 'Y' then  'QC APPROVED' ELSE 'NOT QC APPROVED'
   END VENDOR_QC_TYPE,
```

Comment: `WHEN p.template_id THEN` (effectively) - you appear to have forgotten to do *something* with the value you're selecting.

Answer (score 2):

You need some sort of comparison with the subquery, such as `exists`:

```
 case when exists (select . . .
```

Your question doesn't specify the actual logic you want, so there are other possibilities such as `=` or `not exists`.